# Porque a função após o map executa primeiro?

Tags: javascript, json, react

Estou aprendendo um pouso sobre React, e esse tipo de situação já me ocorreu várias vezes, já procurei sobre async/await, promisses e coisas semelhantes, porém eu gostaria de entender o porque isso acontece e a maneira correta de se fazer.

Nesse código de exemplo eu quero montar um objeto onde um dos campos é um array de veiculos, no banco tenho 2 tabelas separadas, somente depois do map finalizado quero exeutar o res, deixei uns console.log para ver como esta sendo executado e a parte 2 executa primeiro que a 1, e eu acho que a forma que está o codigo está síncrono.

codigo:

```
app.get("/clientes", function(req, res){
   let filtro = [];
   let clientes = [];
   let ssql = 'SELECT * FROM CLIENTES';
   
   
   executeQuery(ssql, filtro, function(err, result){
       if(err){
           res.status(500).json(err);
       } else{
           clientes = result;
           clientes.map(cliente => {
               let ssql2 = 'SELECT * FROM VEICULOS WHERE CLIENTE_ID = '+ cliente.id;
               executeQuery(ssql2, filtro, function(err, result2){
                   if(err){
                       res.status(500).json(err);
                   } else{
                       cliente.veiculos = result2
                       console.log(1)
                   }
               });
           })
           console.log(2)
           res.status(200).json(clientes)
       }
   }); 
   
});
```

Porque o resultado fica 2,1,1 no console e não 1,1,2? No caso me retornando clientes vazio pois ainda nao executou o map

Answer (score -2):

Porque o map é uma Promise e voce nao está aguardando ela terminar para continuar.

para executar na ordem que voce quer:

1. Colocar o map em volta de uma Promise e declarar o iterador como async.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
else{
       clientes = result;
      await Promise.all(clientes.map(async cliente => {
           let ssql2 = 'SELECT * FROM VEICULOS WHERE CLIENTE_ID = '+ cliente.id;
           executeQuery(ssql2, filtro, function(err, result2){
               if(err){
                   res.status(500).json(err);
               } else{
                   cliente.veiculos = result2
                   console.log(1)
               }
           });
       }))
       console.log(2)
       res.status(200).json(clientes)
   }
```

Mas, sendo sincero, voce nao deveria estar usando Array.map, deveria estar usando for...of: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

map só deve ser usado quando o retorno do map vai ser utilizado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, mas mesmo com o await continua executando o res primeiro que o map, colocando um timeout apos o map resolve, por isso me confundo ainda com essas promise, pra mim com o await seria obrigado esperar o map terminar, vou ver sobre o for await of, obrigado.

Comment: **map é uma Promise?** Você tem certeza disso? Poderia por favor mostrar na documentação [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) onde está escrito o que afirma?

Comment: O map async retorna um array de promises na verdade. Colocando esse array dentro de um Promise.all(), o problema do rapaz é solucionado.

Comment: O await só declara que é uma Promise. É necessário o Promise.all() em volta do map.